# How to make Cassandra Inconsistent across nodes?

Tags: cassandra

I need to run some negative tests with the application connecting to Cassandra. What I want to test is how application behaves when the data is not consistent across multiple Cassandra nodes. Below are few things that I tried. Note, I am using replication factor as 2 and number of Cassandra nodes in cluster is 3. Moreover read and write consistency is kept as 1.

- Bring down Cassandra services on few nodes
- plug out network cable for one of the cassandra nodes, insert data
  into other Cassandra node and put back network cable.
- Heavily load Cassandra nodes while test is happening.

In all scenarios, replication was quick enough. As soon as the node which is down is brought up or network cable is plugged in replay happens and data is available on other node.

Any suggestion on trying to reproduce data inconsistency will be helpful. Please note, I have used a Embedded Cassandra and have mocked few tests, but I would like to replicate actual inconsistency so that application behavior can be tested thoroughly.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you want to prove something? Inconsistency in Cassandra can happen if we didn't configure correctly. What is all about your application and what are you going to achieve once you brought Cassandra inconsistency?

Comment: I want to add safe guards against data inconsistency and I don't want application behave differently when data stored on one node is not retrieved from other.

Comment: So you must first understand how data is read in a Cassandra cluster.

Answer (score 2):

You must understand how Cassandra reads or writes data.

In Cassandra cluster say for e.g. you have 4 nodes and replication factor as 3. Then each node will be assigned a Token Range based on the partitioner. As per our e.g. in a 4 node cluster say the Node 1 has token A, Node 2 has token B, Node 3 has token C, Node 4 has token D.

Insertion can be triggered from any node, So that node will be a coordinator node. When a data is inserted then Cassandra computes the token based on the parititioner and checks in which token range the data will fit. If your data is computed and identified the token as C then it will be inserted from Node 3 till the number of replicas (3) in a circular manner. So inserted in Node 3, Node 4, Node 1.

Same way when you read the data, your coordinator node computes the token. Say for e.g if you read the data inserted in above e.g. from Node 2 (coordinator node). Then the Node 2 will request data from Node 3, 4, 1 based on your consistency level, it will wait and return the result. Suppose your consistency level is 1 then it will wait till one node has responded and return. 
If the coordinator node doesn't find enough number of replicas to provide the result then it will throw TokenRangeOfflineException. If it identifies any inconsistency of that record in the nodes, then Cassandra will do a read repair for that record which will make the data consistent.

Also Cassandra provides repair mechanism where unread data or frequent deleted data or not replicated correctly. Hence all these makes Cassandra consistent.

To achieve **inconsistency** we cannot tell specific methods by which data becomes inconsistent, but below method might help you to make inconsistent which I have faced:

- Bring Cassandra nodes down frequently one by one when you constantly insert data
- Also do not do regular repair

But this will take more time to make inconsistent. We cannot guarantee any method to make Cassandra inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra has three mechanisms which provide data consistency across replicas:

1. [Hinted handoff](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-arch/datastax_enterprise/dbArch/archRepairNodesHintedHandoff.html):

> If a node becomes unable to receive a particular write, the write's
>   coordinator node preserves the data to be written as a set of hints.
>   When the node comes back online, the coordinator effects repair by
>   handing off hints so that the node can catch up with the required
>   writes.

2. [Read Repair](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-arch/datastax_enterprise/dbArch/archRepairNodesReadRepair.html):

> In read repair, the database sends a digest request to each replica
>   not directly involved in the read. The database compares all replicas
>   and writes the most recent version to any replica node that does not
>   have it.
>
> The database can also perform read repair randomly on a
>   table. The read_repair_chance property set for a table configures the
>   frequency of this operation.

3. [Anti-entropy repair](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-arch/datastax_enterprise/dbArch/archAntiEntropyRepair.html):

> `nodetool repair tool` compares the data across all replicas and then updates
>   the data to the most recent version

As I see, to achieve inconsistent data across replicas you need to avoid invocation of these mechanisms, e.g:

1. Set up cluster with 2 nodes
2. [Disable hinted handoff in cassandra.yaml](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/config/configCassandra_yaml.html#configCassandra_yaml__hinted_handoff_enabled)
3. Set `read_repair_chance` to 0 for the table
4. Set `replication_factor`to 2
5. Switch off one node
6. Perform write requests for the table with `consistency level = ONE`
7. Switch on the node from step 5
8. Do NOT perform `nodetool repair`
9. Data from step 6 should be inconsistent across replicas: node from step 5 should not contain replicas of data from step 6

Comment: This is useful info. Thanks. Tried executing the steps in the order. But somehow still seeing Cassandra is replicating the data just fine